# Ajax request with Async c# servicehandler

Tags: c#, ajax, asynchronous

I execute an jquery ajax request. The destination is a ashx handler.
The problem is that on the backend a second async request is called. Due of this fact, I'll fall in the "error" case of the jquery ajax request (Error: "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending").

Here the code:

Ajax call:

```
      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: 'ajax/HandlerAsync.ashx',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{method: "'+ data.value +'" , meeting: '+ meeting +' }',
                success: function (data, status, xhr) {

                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                }
            });
```

Backend:

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, object extraData)
    {
        httpContext = context;

        string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        dynamic test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        AjaxRequest ajax = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AjaxRequest>(json);

        Async async = new Async(cb, extraData);
        // store a little context for us to use later as well
        async.context = context;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ajax.meeting.EventId))
        {
            var calendarEntryId = sendCalendarInvitations((ajax.meeting));
        }
        else
        {
            updateCalendarInvitations(ajax.meeting);
        }
        async.SetCompleted();

        return async;
    }


  public void EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        // Finish things
        Async async = result as Async;
        async.context.Response.Write("<H1>This is an <i>Asynchronous</i> response!!</H1>");
    }
```

The problem occurs at the following method, which will be called in the send/updatecalendarinvitation on  var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capability);
**By executing this, the "EndProcessRequest" will be called, unfortunately too soon**. I just want it to be called, when the calendarinvitations are made...

```
 AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("{0}/{1}", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthorizationUri"], SettingsHelper.TenantId));
            DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
                    async () =>
                    {

                        var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(this.refreshToken,
                        new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey),
                        SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId);
                        return authResult.AccessToken;
                    });

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capability);

            OutlookServicesClient exClient = new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
           async () =>
           {
               var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByRefreshTokenAsync(this.refreshToken,
                   new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey),
                   dcr.ServiceResourceId);
               return authResult.AccessToken;
           });
            return exClient;
```

The backend code works fine, the methods will all be called. But I just want the right feedback.
I looking forwand for your feedback. 
Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to tell from the posted code, but it looks like the various "client" classes are possibly taking `Action` callbacks. In this case, the `async` lambdas will become `async void`, which can cause the error you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok solved. 
I wrapped the context (last code section from above) in a seperate Task, which don't fire the "EndprocessRequest".

```
 var client = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run<OutlookServicesClient>(() => {
            return o365Api.CreateOutlookClientAsync("Calendar");
        });
```